# Ravendb query using a list as criteria

Tags: ravendb

Please could someone help with this query. I'm trying to get a list returned from an index where the id matches any id in a given list.  I've tried:

```
var members =  session.Query<MembersNameIdIndex.Result, MembersNameIdIndex>()
                      .Where(x => list.Any(y => y == x.Id))
                      .AsProjection<MembersNameIdIndex.Result>()
                      .ToList();
```

and

```
var members =  from m in session.Query<MembersNameIdIndex.Result, MembersNameIdIndex>()
                where list.Any(y => y == m.Id)
                select m;              
var projection = members.AsProjection<MembersNameIdIndex.Result>()
                          .ToList();
```

and

```
var members =  from m in session.Query<MembersNameIdIndex.Result, MembersNameIdIndex>()
            where list.Contains(m.Id)
            select m;
var projection = members.AsProjection<MembersNameIdIndex.Result>()
                      .ToList();
```

The error is always the same: `Expression type not supported: System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression`
(For the last 2, it fails on the projection part.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var members =  from m in session.Query<MembersNameIdIndex.Result, MembersNameIdIndex>()
            where m.Id.In(list)
            select m;
var projection = members.AsProjection<MembersNameIdIndex.Result>()
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Ayende, correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think there is any .In operator in linq. In any event, m.Id does not expose an .In option.  All the stack questions I've looked at say to use .Contains to emulate a sql 'in' command.

Comment: The `.In()`  method is from `Raven.Client.Documents.Linq` namespace

Comment: Ahhh now I see! Thanks very much Ayende.  Is there any resource list that shows all the methods in the client api? I looked on raven site and couldn't find anything.